Forbidden control sequence found (newtoks)
I'm trying to convert some LaTeX macros from xespotcolor to Plain TeX, to be able to use a single spot color in my Plain TeX document. I managed to extract several macros, but I'm stuck on
\def\NewSpotColorSpace#1{%
  \expandafter\newtoks\csname #1\endcsname%
  \csname #1\endcsname{}%
}

This results in
Runaway definition?
#1->\expandafter 
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning definition of \NewSpotColorSp
ace.
<inserted text> 
}
<to be read again> 
\newtoks 
l.2   \expandafter\newtoks
                        \csname #1\endcsname%

This answer says that one shouldn't use \newtoks within a definition, and suggests a workaround, but when I change my lines of code to
\def\NewSpotColorSpace#1{%
  \expandafter\csname newtoks\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname%
  \csname #1\endcsname{}%
}

and actually use this macro (running \input spotcolorpantone), I get
! Extra \endcsname.
\NewSpotColorSpace ...csname \csname #1\endcsname 
                                                  \csname #1\endcsname {}
l.1 \NewSpotColorSpace{PANTONE}

It's been a while since I tried to completely read The TeXBook, but my main questions are: why is the first definition invalid (but apparently valid in LaTeX), and why does the second one complain about an extra \endcsname? How am I able to dynamically define a new token, and run it, which is (as far as I can tell) the main purpose of this macro?

You are on the right lines: you need to 'hide' \newtoks in plain TeX, but you also need to get your expansion order right:
\csname newtoks\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname

Done this way, your toks name will be generated by \csname ...\endcsname before construction of \newtoks is complete, so it will 'see the required single following token.

On why you need a change: plain TeX makes \newtoks 'outer', so that token cannot appear inside a definition. LaTeX doesn't do that, because ... well because it's a pain that doesn't really help catch bugs.
